# Avoiding the mistake of comparing number and string

Tags: python, python-2.7

We've all made this kind of mistake in python:

```
if ( number < string ):
```

python silently accepts this and just gives incorrect output.

Thank goodness python 3 finally warns us.  But in some cases python 2.7 is needed.  Is there any way in python 2.7 to guard against this mistake other than "just be careful" (which we all know doesn't work 100% of the time)?

Comment: No there isn't, which is why they changed it in Python 3.x. When writing in Python 2.7 just be careful :)

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could explicitly convert both numbers to `int`. The string will get converted, and the number won't be effected (it's already an int). So this saves you the need to start remembering what type of value the number holds:

```
a = 11
b = "2"
print a > b # prints False, which isn't what you intended
print int(a) > int(b) # prints True
```

EDIT:
As noted in the comments, you cannot assume a number is an integer. However, applying the same train of though with the proper function - `float` should work just fine:

```
a = 11
b = "2"
print a > b # prints False, which isn't what you intended
print float(a) > float(b) # prints True
```

Comment: That's what I was about to suggest, but what if it's a `float` and not an `int`? The OP will need to have all combinations of `int` and `float` for both `a` and `b`.

Comment: "The number won't be effected (it's already an int)" -- how do you know that? `int("1.0")` is an error.

Comment: @DeepSpace good point - better just use `float` - see my edited answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist good point -  better just use float (which should handle integers properly) - see my edited answer

Comment: I think with `float` this is probably the best way. String tests like `isdigit` will also fail on floats (decimal point) so ultimately trying to cast is less code. You might also note that one should be prepared to catch a `ValueError` in case something is casted that can't be cast (like `float('abcde')`).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist converting to `float` will fail if the number has too many digits and is being compared to something very similar. There are also integers that are completely outside the range of `float` but you're less likely to encounter those.

Comment: @MarkRansom If you're getting into the realm of incomparable floats due to the system's floating point precision limitations, you're (a.) pretty far outside the scope of this question and (b.) going to have problems even if your data are not strings!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if I'm reading the question correctly, the desired response of comparing an int and a string is to throw an exception, not try to attempt the comparison anyway. That way you can *fix* the problem instead of band-aiding it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, *really* want to be 100% sure that comparing strings and ints is impossible, you can overload the `__builtin__.int` (and `__builtin__.float`, etc. as necessary) method to disallow comparing ints (and floats, etc) with strings.  It would look like this:

```
import __builtin__

class no_str_cmp_int(int):
    def __lt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is str:
            raise TypeError
        return super.__lt__(other)
    def __gt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is str:
            raise TypeError
        return super.__gt__(other)
    # implement __gte__, __lte__ and others as necessary

# replace the builtin int method to disallow string comparisons
__builtin__.int = no_str_cmp_int

x = int(10)
```

Then, if you attempted to do something like this, you'd receive this error:

```
>>> print x < '15'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    print x < '15'
  File "tmp.py", line 7, in __lt__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
```

There is a major caveat to this approach, though.  It only replaces the `int` function, so every time you created an int, you'd have to pass it through the function, as I do in the declaration of `x` above.  Literals will continue to be the original `int` type, and as far as I am aware there is no way to change this.  However, if you properly create these objects, they will continue to work with the 100% assurance you desire.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar, it made my ipython blow up!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the string or any data type to float first. 
When two data types are same, then only we can compare them.

Suppose,

```
a = "10"
b= 9.3
c=9
```

We want to add a,b,c.. So,

So, the correct way to add these three is to convert them to same data type and then add.

```
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)

print a+b+c
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if each variable is an int like this :

```
if ( isinstance(number, int) and isinstance(string, int) ):
   if (number < string):
      Do something
   else:
      Do something else
else :
   print "NaN"
```

*Edit:
To check for a float too the code should be :

```
if ( isinstance(number, (int,float )) and isinstance(string, (int,float) ) ):
```

Comment: Again, see the comments on the top answer. What if the number is a float? By your code, some very important numbers like pi and Euler's constant are "not a number" because they're not integral!